# jQuery fade, animate and toggle?

Tags: jquery, toggle, fade

I had asked this question on Forrst and received two code responses. One worked and one didn't. I was hoping someone would be able to explain to me why the second one does not work.

My goal was to have my search hidden by default. When you click a search icon, it will toggle the search to fade in and move slightly to the left. If you click the search icon again, it will fade out and move to the right.

Here is the code that worked:

```
  $(function() {
    var search = $('#searchform');
    search.css('opacity', 0);

  $('#search-img').toggle(function() {
    search.animate({opacity: 1}, {queue: false, duration: 'slow'});
    search.animate({ left: "-10px" }, 'slow');
  },
 function() {
   search.animate({opacity: 0}, {queue: false, duration: 'slow'});
   search.animate({ left: "+10px" }, 'slow');
  } 
  );      

});
```

Here is the code that when I click on the search icon nothing happens:

```
$(function() {
var search = $('#searchform').css('opacity', 0),
    i = 0;

$('#search-img').click(function() {
    search.animate({opacity: 'toggle', left: i % 2 == 0 ? 0 : -10});
    i++;
});
});
```

Does anyone see what the issue with the second code is?

Answer (score 0):

The var i won't be available, since it's not a global var.  To make something global within $(), you just need to assign it to the window object.

The fix is this:

```
$(function() {
var search = $('#searchform').css('opacity', 0),
    window.i = 0;

$('#search-img').click(function() {
    search.animate({opacity: 'toggle', left: i % 2 == 0 ? 0 : -10});
    window.i++;
});
});
```

Comment: I am getting this error when I tried that "Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token ."

Comment: I just copied and pasted your code, and add the window object.  The error is the comma after css('opacity', 0).  It should be a semicolon ; instead.

Comment: I ended up hiding the search by default for people with JS turned on in my css file. I then made my jQuery look like this    $$('#search-img').click(function() {
    search.animate({opacity: 'toggle', left: i % 2 == 0 ? 0 : -10});
    window.i++;
}); and it toggles on and off now but does not move at all.